# How to webscrape in python and put scraped items into a database?

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, webapi

I want to be able to scrape tech products from websites and put them into a database, but I am not sure how to do this. Would anybody be able to share with me how to scrape from websites using Python, set up a database and put the scraped products into set database.

I tried looking at methods to scrape from websites in python but I don't understand how to do this.

Comment: Take a day and watch the [John Watson Rooney Youtubes](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8tgRQ7DOzAbn9L7zDL8mLg) . Learning python or any programming discipline is a time consuming project. Be prepared. Good luck.

Comment: And sorry, but your question is off-topic here. Please read the text of the [tag:web-scraping] tag you added to your question.   Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ,   [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  ,  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [mcve] before posting more Qs here. Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this task you would need to learn the basics of html, css, database and finally python.

1. Learn how HTML page is structured.
2. Learn Database (eg. SQL).
3. Learn Python.

Learn how database are handled through python.(simplest database to start with would be sqlite3 it's module comes pre-installed with python)
Now you would need to learn some web scraping and parsing libraries available in python my favourite is BeautifulSoup.

And you're done now.. go start scraping websites.. practice on some simple websites first..
Remember not all websites are easy to scrape, and also there isn't any website which cannot be scraped just the difficulty increases.
To start with you could check this simple tutorial: https://github.com/oxylabs/Python-Web-Scraping-Tutorial